# Threading model of Windows Store application

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm creating Windows Store application, that retrieves data asynchronously from web service and then updates the UI with the data. I've had several problems when accessing Application.Current.Resources in code(RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD).

Where I can find some explanation on how the app in launched, which threads are spawned during the app lifetime, and what I can do and access, and what can't?

Comment: [The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/08/25/456344.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, now it's clearer. Still have some questions: so, for the UI objects STA threads are used, right? So when I'm trying to get App.Current.Resources from UI thread I get my exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Store applications follow the WPF threading model in which there is a single UI thread called the Dispatcher.  All UI updates/modifications/etc must occur on the dispatcher thread.  The error you are getting is that you're trying to update the UI on a background thread.

.Net 4.5 uses a new async/await mechanism for managing asynchronous calls.  So:

```
public async List<Foo> GetMyFooData()
{
    return await _myWebService.GetFooData();
}
```

What is happening under the hood is that an asynchronous method is being generated by the compiler so that you don't block the UI thread.

I suspect that you're trying to access Access items that are expecting to be retrieved by the Dispatcher and this is why you're erroring.